# Is there a way to pass object property in v-for to Vue data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using axios to fetch API data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. I have been trying to get the name of the user based on the userId of each post so that I can display it in html.

ex:
**POSTS**

- post.id = 1
- post.userId = 1

**USERS**

- user.id = 1
- user.name = Leanne Graham

---

Here is my HTML so far. I've tried v-model for post.userId, but for now I don't know how to pass this to data.

```
<div id="app">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search post" v-model="search">
  <div class="post-card" v-for="post in filteredPosts" v-model="post.userId">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post.userId}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js'></script>
```

Here is my .js file. As you can see I commented out my attempt to fetch user details. I've tried doing "res.data.name" but upon trying it out in the console, I got "undefined."

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      users: [],
      search: '',
    }
  },
  created(){
    const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  axios.get(baseURL + '/posts?_limit=20')
    .then(res => this.posts = res.data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    // axios.get(baseURL + '/users' )
    // .then(res => this.users = res.data.name)
    // .catch(err => console.log(err));
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.posts.filter(post => {
        return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don’t need the v-model, and you don’t have a filteredPosts array.

Comment: I have a method for filtering already, and I realized it's a mistake on my part not to include that code in my question above. I'll edit it in so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you mean / try to achieve. You can't really pass data that way using V-model. Instead, I filter the user array to match the post ID using `users.find`.

*The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.* More info on `.find` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) .

I've created an example below.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      users: [],
    }
  },
  created() {
    const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

    axios.get(baseURL + '/posts?_limit=20')
      .then(res => {

        this.posts = res.data
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    axios.get(baseURL + '/users/')
      .then(res => this.users = res.data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div class="post-card" v-for="post in posts">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>Post ID: {{post.userId}}</p>
    <p>Username: {{users.find(user => user.id === post.userId).name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I now see that there some errors in the console. That's because `.find` is called before `posts` is fully initialized. Maybe you should create a method for the filtering and check whether `posts` already has data.

Comment: Careful here, in some cases, `users.find(user => user.id === post.userId)` may return `undefined` (either the list of users is not complete or post.userId references a bad user). But nonetheless, the snippet is good.

Comment: I have a method for filtering already, and I realized it's a mistake on my part not to include that code in my question above. Though, your solution worked as I tried it out with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="post-card" :key="post.title" v-for="post in posts">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post.userId}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
v-for="post in posts" //posts == this.posts
```